# Ошибка, когда закидываю проект, сделанный на Node.js, на Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

Проблема заключается в том, что, когда мною был закинут проект, сделанный на Node.js, на Heroku, в консоли(CMD) появились ошибки и сам проект не запускается. До того, как тестировать проект на Heroku, я пробовал его просмотреть локально, т.е. без хостинга, и всё работает. Возможно, это проблема в .gitingnore, потому что как только сделал Git, то начались такие проблемы. Делал всё по инструкции. Не понимаю, в чём может быть проблема. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Репозиторий на GitHub: https://github.com/ZzZimaAa/BMV

Сам .gitignore (1):

```
logs
*.log
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
pids
*.pid
*.seed
*.pid.lock
lib-cov
coverage
.nyc_output
.grunt
bower_components
.lock-wscript
build/Release
node_modules/
jspm_packages/
typings/
.npm
.eslintcache
.node_repl_history
*.tgz
.yarn-integrity
.env
.next
package-lock.json
```

И .gitignore (2):

```
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js
/coverage
/build
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
yarn.lock
```

Консоль(CMD):

[image]

[image]

Comment: А на хероке монго развёрнута без приколов? Ну, то есть вообще развёрнута? Строка ури которая, может не захардкожена, а лежит где-то в `.env` файлике? А он в игноре. Думаю, там собака зарыта

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну в ошибке же всё написано. Файл `/app/lib/mongoose-config.js` строка 7, символ 6. В uri для подключения к базе ты вместо строки передаёшь `undefined`.

```
.connect(config.mongoUri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

Ну и дальше раскручиваем:

```
const config = require('./config')
```

```
mongoUri: process.env.MONGO_URI,
```

Вывод: переменной среды `MONGO_URI` нет.

Открываешь админку хероку вместе со справкой и настраиваешь.